# What is the appropriate way to handle several commands instead of switch statement in C language

Tags: c

I have 1st program that handles commands which comes from other 2nd program through System V message queue in Linux.

what I have done is

1- (in second program) send the commands into System V message queue

2- (in first program) read the messages form System V message queue then convert the commands which is in string format into integer value so I can use switch statement.

3- based in the value I call the appropriate function.

but this is too hard to handle every command.

so what is the best way to solve this big switch statement?

Comment: I would mantain the *conversion+big switch* road. The conversion is not so difficult if you first populate a static array, matching in every item the strings containing all the accepted commands with the enum item to be used in the switch.

Comment: Another method is an array of structures that maps strings to functions. You scan the array looking for a matching string, then call the corresponding function.

Comment: How many commands do you have?

Comment: there are more than 30 commands so as I said using switch statement is not a good solution,also searching the whole array would take O(n)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a handful of commands, a simple if/elsif will do.

```
enum commands cmd_num = UNKNOWN_COMMAND;

if( strcmp(cmd_string, "this") ) {
    cmd_num = THIS_COMMAND;
}
else if( strcmp(cmd_string, "that") ) {
    cmd_num = THAT_COMMAND;
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command: %s", cmd_string);
}

switch(cmd_num) {
  case THIS_COMMAND:
    this();
    break;
  case THAT_COMMAND:
    that();
    break;
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command #%d", cmd_num);
}
```

But why not cut out the middle man?

```
if( strcmp(cmd_string, "this") ) {
    this();
elsif( strcmp(cmd_string, "that") ) {
    that();
}
else {
    fprintf("Unknown command: %s", cmd_string);
}
```

If you plan on having a lot of commands you can put them into a [hash table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.62/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-lookup) for ease of addition and lookup. The key is the command string. The value could be an integer with a separate switch statement (or another hash table) to run the command.

Or, once again, we can cut out the middle man and make it a function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmodule.h>

void this() {
    puts("this");
}

void that() {
    puts("that");
}

GHashTable *init_commands() {
    return g_hash_table_new( g_str_hash, g_str_equal );
}

void add_command(GHashTable *commands, const char *command, void(*func_ptr)(void)) {
    g_hash_table_insert(commands, g_strdup(command), (void *)func_ptr);
}

void run_command(GHashTable *commands, const char *command) {
    void(*func_ptr)(void) = g_hash_table_lookup(commands, command);
    if( func_ptr ) {
        (*func_ptr)();
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown command: %s", command);
    }
}

int main() {    
    GHashTable *commands = init_commands();
    add_command(commands, "this", this);
    add_command(commands, "that", that);

    run_command(commands, "this");
}
```

The trade-off is that all commands must now have the same signature. This is common for remote command handlers, but it takes some getting used to. Which way you choose depends on how your project works.

Comment: using if/else or switch statement is a good way for handle few commands is a straight forward , but when there are a lots of command and it might be growth it's not a good practice , I heard about hash table which is the best structure for searching  an item . is there any recommended article or resource explain it ?

Comment: @root_ Performance wise, a switch will generally perform the same with any number of options, while an if/elseif will get slower as it checks each condition. Hash tables are a basic data structure and any good book or article on data structures in C will cover hash tables. Try perhaps the [CS50 videos on Hash Tables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvzVHwrrub0).

Comment: thank you very much for the recommendation video , it's very helpful and easy to understand